# Is there a way to have more vertex colors per mesh? Or at least some kind of workaround?

Tags: vertex-colors, vertex-paint

At the moment it won't let me create more than eight, the add button doesn't work after that number.
[image: -]

I use these for different "handpainted" lighting effects for different scenes with the model. So I can't delete some to make more.

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to bake to image texture?  That's what I'd recommend doing.

Comment: Hi Nathan! sorry if this is an ignorant question but, wouldn't the quality of my vertex paint get affected by the texture size if I bake it? It's only 128*256 px

Comment: Its unlikely to lose any resolution-- generally, you have more texels than vertices, but it depends on the vertex count.  But then, if you want, bake it to a larger texture.  There's nothing that fixes the size of your texture images, and there's nothing saying you have to use the same sizes of textures for everything (or even the same UV maps.)

Comment: Oh, I think I'll try baking those effects to a larger texture and save them to use them later then. Thanks Nathan!